# How to register Associated Domains with Xcode 11?

Tags: xcode11, associated-domains

I've been trying to add Associated Domains capability to my App but can't find it using Xcode 11. Has this feature disabled upon version 11? [image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem was with my Developer Account, it wasn't fully approved by Apple. So, as soon it was approved, Associate Domains (and also Notifications) appeared in my Capabilities list. Don't know why they would limit development due to account status but they did.

Comment: The Capability library shows only the capabilities available to the target type and your program membership. If you are not a member of the Apple Developer Program, the capabilities you can add are limited.

Answer (score 24):

**If you don't have a paid Apple developer account**, remove "✓" from Automatically manage signing. Then "Associated domain" will be available.

worked for me in Xcode 12 !

[image]

Answer (score 9):

1. In xcode go to Editor > Add capability

[image: Add capability]

2. Just double click on "associated" domains in the window that opens

[image]

3. Add your domain

[image]

Comment: I know where it was supposed to be (like in my screenshot) but the problem was why wasn't there!

Comment: upvoted that you mentioned to do a double click to add associated domains

Answer (score 2):

Turn off `Automatically manage signing` to add `Associated Domains`

Before:

[image]

After

[image]